# Tweetsharp does not obtain method listFollowerOf

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

Help please.

I try to get Twitter followers in my database, however 'TweetSharp.TwitterService' does not contain a definition for 'ListFollowerOf' and no extension method 'ListFollowerOf' accepting a first argument of type 'TweetSharp.TwitterService' could be found. (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Using Tweetsharp you can get a list of a user's followers using the following code:

```
var twitterService = new TwitterService("yourConsumerKey", "yourConsumerSecret");
twitterService.AuthenticateWith("yourToken", "yourTokenSecret");

var userProfile = twitterService.GetUserProfile(new GetUserProfileOptions { IncludeEntities = true, SkipStatus = false });

var followerOptions = new ListFollowersOptions 
                    { 
                        IncludeUserEntities = true, 
                        ScreenName = userProfile.ScreenName, 
                        SkipStatus = false, 
                        UserId = userProfile.Id 
                    };

var usersfollowers = twitterService.ListFollowers(followerOptions);
```

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22122525/203371 for an extended example of how to get follower information.